# Ubertesters: Unable to extract project data : incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 after to try upload ipa file(iOS-app archive)

Tags: ios, swift, ubertesters

I'm trying to upload iOS-app (.ipa archive) to Ubertesters service, but after upload I get an error: `incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8`.
How can I fix it?
https://ubertesters.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display Name must be written in latin. Edit it if needed in projectFile->General->Display Name